# Decimal troubles in aspnet core / ef core entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

My website has a form with a number input that takes decimal numbers. This is sent back to the controller in a viewmodel. When validation passes, the viewmodel is converted to an entity like this:

```
quotation.WidthMeters = model.WidthMeters.
```

So here is where the fun starts.

My website is in the Dutch culture. We use comma for decimal seperators. So the user inputs 2,40 in the form. This is sent back. I can see that the data in the viewmodel contains 2.40 which is the US way of saying 2,40. Now when this value is assigned to the entity, it all of a sudden changes to 240. So `quotation.WidthMeters` is now 240, but the property assigning it (`model.WithMeters`) is 2.40.

Why?

(probably important to add: I made my controller run in the InvariantCulture by adding the following two lines to the constructor of the controller:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
```

The entity is in the same project)

**update**

When I add the following to my `startup.cs`, it works:

```
app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
        {
            DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US"),
            SupportedCultures = new [] {new CultureInfo("en-US") },
            SupportedUICultures = new [] { new CultureInfo("en-US") }
        });
```

It doesn't work when I change the culture to *nl-NL*, however I prefer using the Dutch culture since that will also fix the dates.

**update 2**

In my form I used the `<input type="number" />` field which at least in Chrome and Firefox always send the number back with a decimal point.
I switched back to a textfield and changed the cultures to nl-NL. Now I can enter the numbers with decimal comma and it is handled correctly by the server.

So TRWTF is, Why does a browser show a comma in the number field but send it back with a dot?

Comment: So you're telling us that assigning a decimal to another decimal will change the value from 2.40 to 240?

Comment: @user743414 see my edit

Comment: Did you install https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization/?

Comment: Can you create a minimal working example to reproduce this issue?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft.AspnetCore.All which contains AspnetCore.Localization but I did not configure anything

Comment: This isn't a new issue and has nothing to do with any ASP.NET bug. It's a matter of *internationalization*, not localization. The *browser's* culture is different than the server's. ASP.NET tries to use the *browser's* culture unless a different culture is specified in `web.config` or programmatically, as part of the user's settings. Developer machines are often set to English-language locales, meaning that the *browser itself* reports an `en-US` culture to the server.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos afaik aspnet core doesn't have a web.config. My browser was also set to Dutch. The application was set to Dutch.

Comment: @jao it *does* have configuration and it doesn't matter where that is stored. What matters is that the **browser** sent the wrong language headers. Check Rick Strahl's [Auto selecting cultures in ASP.NET](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/mar/27/auto-selecting-cultures-for-localization-in-aspnet), even though it's not about .Core. `UICulture` is what affects the messages. `Culture` is what affects parsing and formatting.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you. I set the culture in the startup.cs but the problem is probably the browser sending the data with a dot instead of comma, even when it is showing a comma to the user. I 'fixed' it now by using textboxes instead of `input type=number`. But i agree that the problem is more on the browser side than aspnet.

Comment: @jao it's not a "problem", it's how the web works. Different apps have different requirements. I found the ASP.NET Core specific do section [Implement a strategy to select the language/culture for each request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization#implement-a-strategy-to-select-the-languageculture-for-each-request). Lots of options - the default is to use the headers but you can also pass the language as a query parameter or cookie

Comment: See here http://imgur.com/a/hgQim for what I mean with problem.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound correct. You should double check your types in the assignment and also their values (e.g. in the debugger). It just doesn't make sense that assigning a decimal to another decimal in the .NET runtime will change the value.

Comment: This has nothing to do with .NET changing types. It's about internationalization - the browser uses a *different* culture than the server. ASP.NET handles this already, unless someone hard-codes the wrong culture, or simply uses the wrong one. Like a developer whose machine locale is set to `en-US` trying to enter a localized string.